# Error 404 only for some file types (.woff, .map) in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, woff, woff2

I have an already advanced project with spring boot with thymeleaf and recently I went to add a new template with awesome font, among others.

The problem is:

Only for some types of files I always get a 404 error (Example .map, .woff, .ttf, among others).
[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60dTp.png)

As they were able to check the .map of the 404, but the .css loaded correctly, this already discards the issue of incorrect path.

I really need your help! Thank you!

Segue algumas das configurações importantes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


@Bean
protected SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/public/**",  "/login/**", "/logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                .loginPage("/login/signIn")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login/signIn?error=true"))
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).httpBasic();

    http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .expiredUrl("/login/notAuthorized")
            .and()
            .sessionFixation()
            .migrateSession();

    http.logout()
            .logoutUrl("/login/SignOut")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

    return http.build();
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder =
            http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
}
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/public/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .setCachePeriod(3600)
            .resourceChain(true);
}
}
```

Comment: After days with the problem, I basically solved the problem of restarting IntelliJ/computer